# Create Dynamic html Templating in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a node.js project in which i want to implement creating a template. Basically, i have a html skeleton.

```
<html>
<head>
--- script file---
</head>
<body>
here i want to include html table on click the button

</body>
</html>
```

When i click the button, i want to include a html string which i have already been
coded. I have tried with following html string.

```
        html+=
        '<div style="margin-top: 2%">' +
        '<table border-collapse: collapse; border="1" width="100%" style="background-color:#b3b3b3 " font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Segoe UI, Optima, Arial, sans-serif cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7">' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th align="center" style="font-size: 12px">DEMO CTS' +
        '</th>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="margin-top:2%">' +
        '<table border-collapse: collapse; border="1" style="width: 100%;font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Segoe UI, Optima, Arial, sans-serif" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">' +
        '<tr style="background-color: #b3b3b3;text-align: center;">' +
        '<th colspan="4" style="font-size: 12px"><b>BACKGROUND CHECK - SUMMARY</b></th>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3;width: 25%;font-size: 12px" align="left"><b>CMC APPLICANT ID</b></th>' +
        '<td style="font-size: 12px" width="28%">'+data.applicantId+'</td>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3;width: 25%;font-size: 12px" align="left"><b>VENDOR RF-ID</b></th>' +
        '<td style="font-size: 12px">'+data.vendorId+'</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3;font-size: 12px" align="left"><b>RECRUITMENT BRANCH</b></th>' +
        '<td style="font-size: 12px">'+data.branch+'</td>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3;font-size: 12px; width: 15%" align="left"><b>NSR IT_PIN</b></th>' +
        '<td style="font-size: 12px">'+data.nsrPin+'</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3;font-size: 12px;width: 15%" align="left"><b>NAME OF THE CANDIDATE</b></th>' +
        '<td colspan="3" style="font-size: 12px">'+data.name+'</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3;font-size: 12px" align="left"><b>DATE OF BIRTH</b></th>' +
        '<td style="font-size: 12px">'+data.dob+'</td>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3; font-size: 12px;width: 25%" align="left">FINAL BGC STATUS (RED,GREEN)</th>' +
        '<td style="background-color:orange">Amber</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th style="background-color: #b3b3b3;font-size: 12px; width: 10%;" align="left"><b>CATEGORY (CAMPUS/DT/EP/EP FROM CAMPUS)</b></th>' +
        '<td style="font-size: 12px">'+data.category+'</td>' +
        '<td style="font-size: 12px" colspan="2"></td></tr></table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple templating modules for Node.js, such as EJS or Jade. I'd recommend to use those, instead of creating one yourself.

See

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade

Comment: I need to generate a template as html string. So that i can generate a pdf with the help of the html string. If you have any idea pls do let me know..

Comment: Why would I if you downvote a legit answer? And first, you should understand that these technologies **ARE** creating what you call an "html string", meaning html code. You can take the output and do whatever you want with it, be it converting to PDF